# Batch file, I want to supress the Windows Script Host Pop-Ups

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, mdt

I use the MDT ([Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dn475741.aspx)) with WDS ([Windows Deployment Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windowsserver/dd448616.aspx)) in my organization. I call a CMD-File with `cmd /c %scriptroot%\HP_Win_7.bat` within the task sequence.

Content of the batch file:

```
slmgr /ilc c:\support\zertifikate\HP.xrm-ms
slmgr /ipk 74T2M-DKDBC-788W3-H689G-6P6GT
slmgr /ato
```

During execution of the batch file I get 3 pop-ups from Windows Script Host which I have to acknowledge by pressing "OK" or "Enter". The Batch pauses, until I acknowledge the pop-up. If not, the cmd-file pauses.

I want a solution to hide those pop-ups or automatically acknowledge them.

The script loads a certificate file and a generic key and activates windows.
(The Windows-Key is generic, for HP Win 7 PCs)

Comment: `MDT`? `WDS`? `slmgr`?

Comment: [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dn475741.aspx), [Windows Deployment Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windowsserver/dd448616.aspx), [Software Licensing Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502529.aspx)

Comment: @Mark Setchell Sorry for not explaining those abbreviations, will do better next time, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on who is generating the pop-ups. If they are directly generated by the `slmgr.vbs` script, then you have two simple options:

- You can directly request the execution of the script in *"batch"* mode, and you will get no ouput

  ```
  slmgr.vbs //b /ilc c:\support\zertifikate\HP.xrm-ms
  ...
  ```
- If you want to keep the output (but no popups from the script), instead of executing the script under `wscript.exe` (the default, used when you directly invoke the script), use `cscript.exe` to execute it in console mode, to get all the output written into the console

  ```
  cscript.exe //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /ilc c:\support\zertifikate\HP.xrm-ms
  ...
  ```

Comment: Yes, they were generated by slmgr.vbs. No more pop-ups, Thanks!